# Is there a way to prevent "crossover" iterations when using scipy.optimize.libprog's solver "highs-ipm"?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, linear-optimization, highs

Is there an option to prevent "crossover" when calling highs-ipm solver via scipy.optimize.linprog?  It appears that the "standalone" solver (see https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS) has an option "--run_crossover arg".  I just wonder if this is reachable via Python's scipy interface?

The documentation page for linpropg does not list this as a parameter, which of course suggests the negative answer.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-highs-ipm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 1.11.1 of scipy, it is possible to pass *unknown options* to the solver like `run_crossover=False`. Scipy will generate a warning but the options will be passed to the solver.

It is possible to check the number of iterations performed in the crossover with `sol.crossover_nit`. The result should be 0.

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

# Define c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq, bounds
...

# Define options
solver = 'highs-ipm'
params = {'run_crossover': False}

# Optimize
sol = linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq, bounds, method=solver, options=params)

# Check the number of iteration in crossover
print(sol.crossover_nit)  # it should be 0
```

You can check all options [`HighsOptions.pxd`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/81ccb98559917df8d7704c31218da936e7b83f1e/scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/HighsOptions.pxd#L40-L111)